# Can a linux client in a multicast network get to know the source ip?

Tags: multicast, igmp

Supose I'm added as a client in a small multicast network with L2 switches and one unique router that is the LHR that uses IGMPv2. Can I (legally if possible) forward some signal that will give me the LHR or the source IP address?

Comment: Hm its unclear what you want to, but Look on the Management of the switch it might be give an hint

Comment: @djdomi I think I understand why it is not clear. I'm searching for the node that created the multicast network. Not just a source

Comment: so fixed your issue?

Comment: not yet, but I found the command ip maddr show which is great

Comment: oh yeah and nmap is good too